# issue with converting auto-py-to-exe with tkinter SystemExit: pre-safe-import-module hook failed

Tags: python, tkinter, hook, pyinstaller

I'm getting an issue when I convert Tkinter code to exe  my libraries are follows

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from selenium import webdriver
import webdriver_manager.chrome
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
import argparse
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from numpy import random
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import os

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

and I'm getting this error and I removed some lines in the log file.

```
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --icon "D:/fiver/amazone/Danleech-Simple-Amazon.ico"  "D:/fiver/amazone/guit/onlyui.py"

#removed some logs

    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 431, in _safe_import_module
    hook_module.pre_safe_import_module(hook_api)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py", line 40, in pre_safe_import_module
    raise SystemExit("pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.")
SystemExit: pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```